# Finding $x$ and $y$ from two linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two linear equations:

$110x + y = 10$

and

$95x + y = 0$

The solution given in the course I have is $x = 2/3$ and $y = -63.33$
No workings are given.

I am not sure how to solve for $x$ and $y$. I tried rearranging the first equation to find $x$:

$x = 10-y/110$

Then do I substitute this for $x$ into the other equation?

$95 (10-y/110) + y = 10$

Not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: What is $d$? Is that $y$?

Comment: Sorry, yes $d$ is actually meant to be $y$.

Comment: I have now corrected this.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract second from first you get:
$$15x = 10$$
which means $x = \frac{2}{3}$
So use any equation of the two to find $y$ as
$$y = -95x = -95\frac{2}{3} = -\frac{190}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$15x=10$$ or
$$x=\frac{2}{3}.$$
Thus, $$y=-\frac{95\cdot2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Don't rush your steps.

When you solve for $x$, you have:
$$110x = 10 - y$$
$$\Rightarrow x = \frac{10}{\color{red}{110}} - \frac{y}{110}$$
$$\Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{11} - \frac{y}{110}$$

Substituting into $95x + y = 0$ we have:

$$95 \left(\frac{1}{11} - \frac{y}{110} \right)+y = \color{red}{0}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{95}{11} - \frac{95}{110}y + y = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{95}{11} - \frac{95}{110}y + \frac{110}{110}y = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow - \frac{95}{110}y + \frac{110}{110}y = 0 - \frac{95}{11}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{15}{110}y = -\frac{95}{11}$$
$$\Rightarrow y = -\frac{95}{11} \cdot \frac{110}{15}$$
$$= -\frac{19}{1} \cdot \frac{10}{3}$$
$$= -\frac{190}{3}$$

Now you can substitute $y$ into any of the two equations to find $x$.

Note: Of course, eliminating $y$ from both equations is much simpler.

Comment: @Moo I've edited my answer.